# Can browserify combine my js files without including own code

Tags: javascript, browserify

Can browserifyJS compile my javascript  project (browser code) in a single static file without adding own code at the top of the compiled file? The structure of my project is very simple (5-7 submodules) so I don't want to see any dependency management in runtime.

Is there any other tool to do this? (r.js or something else?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible for you to do this just by using Browserify alone, or you can use [grunt-browserify](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify). The impact will be you have to get use to writing node.js/CommonJS style `require()`.

An example is avaiable [here](http://numbers.brighterplanet.com/2011/08/04/add-node-js-commonjs-style-require-to-client-side-javascript-with-browserify/).

Comment: I think Browserify adds some dependency management code (definitions for `require` and `exports`) in resulting script runtime code. Isn't it?

Comment: if you are familiar with angular, you can take a look at https://github.com/mallim/sbangular/blob/master/src/main/resources/js/app.js, the dependency is actually being defined in the code and not done by Browserify explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The possible solution is to use [Grunt requirejs plugin](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-requirejs) with [AMDclean](https://www.npmjs.org/package/amdclean)